# Conditional lead variable in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I want to create conditional lead/lag variables that would that capture pre and post years of an agreement signed by countries.

More precisely, I want to create the following variables:

1. a variable that is =1 in the 4 years pre/before the agreement, 0 otherwise
2. a variable that is =1 5 years pre the agreement and
3. a variable that is =1 only after 4 years after the ratification

I have a country-year data (please see below for the sample of the data). The `X1` indicates whether a country has signed the agreemen (=1), or not (=0).

The variables I want to create (*my expected output*) are manually done in the sample data below, labeled as `X1_pre4`, `X1_pre5` and `X1_post5`. The first captures the 4 years (or up to 4 years) before the agreement is signed. The second captures the 5 years before the agreement is signed. And the last variable captures the 5 years after the agreement is signed (it starts the same year as the agreement is signed, but it's fine if it starts after that, too).

I have been suggested to use some sort of "split-operate-unsplit" construct. But I personally think that this is can be done in dplyr, using the mutate command.

Currently, I've been trying to work with this logic:

```
data$X1_pre4[data$year<="1972" & data$X1=="0" ] <- "1"
```

But this is not good enough (far away), as I am not sure how to group by country here. Even if I figure this out, it won't do the work as I have over 100 of X's (agreements). I simply need a code that is much smarter.

```
data <-
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 
    1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
    1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 
    1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 
    1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 
    1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 
    1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L), 
    X1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), X1_pre4 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1_pre5 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1_post4 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your expected output for the sample data you give?

Comment: @MauritsEvers my expected output: X1_pre4, X1_pre5 and X1_post5 as I indicate in the text. I'll make it more clear. thanks!

Comment: This is **cross posted** from [R-Help](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg254781.html). Cross posting is not welcome, specially since there is an ongoing thread elsewhere and it seems you are getting answers. Downvote and VTC.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for pointing this out. I couldn't find any information that this was against the rules.  Also: I had no idea that the two forums were connected. In my world it is perfectly reasonable to ask the same question in different forums, and if I get the right help I'll indicate/paste the answer in both forums.

Comment: Ok, to know [SO cross posting etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette) would need a search but the [R-Help posting guide](http://www.R-project.org/posting-guide.html) says that you shouldn't. The two fora are not connected, it's just that the sets of users intersect. Since you didn't know (and I believe you didn't) I will retract my votes. Anyway, you should explain your `dplyr` idea to R-Helpers.

Comment: @RuiBarradas great - thank you  for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would correspond to your logic:

```
check_pre <- function(idx, k) { pre_vec <- sapply(1:length(idx), function(x) +any(idx[x:(pmin(x + k, length(idx)))] %in% 1)); pre_vec[idx == 1] <- 0; return(pre_vec) }
check_post <- function(idx, k) sapply(1:length(idx), function(x) +any(idx[(pmax(x - k, 1)):x] %in% 1))

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(
    idx = +( (lag(X1) == 0 & X1 == 1) | row_number() == 1 & X1 == 1),
    X1_pre4 = check_pre(idx, 4),
    X1_pre5 = check_pre(idx, 5),
    X1_post4 = check_post(idx, 4),
    idx = NULL
  )
```

Basically we create an index of when the agreement occurred, and then check for the rows before/after this index with custom functions `check_pre` and `check_post`.

This is the output:

```
   country year X1 X1_pre4 X1_pre5 X1_post4
1        A 1970  0       1       1        0
2        A 1971  0       1       1        0
3        A 1972  1       0       0        1
4        A 1973  1       0       0        1
5        A 1974  1       0       0        1
6        A 1975  1       0       0        1
7        A 1976  1       0       0        1
8        A 1977  1       0       0        0
9        A 1978  1       0       0        0
10       A 1979  1       0       0        0
11       A 1980  1       0       0        0
12       A 1981  1       0       0        0
13       A 1982  1       0       0        0
14       A 1983  1       0       0        0
15       A 1984  1       0       0        0
16       A 1985  1       0       0        0
17       A 1986  1       0       0        0
18       A 1987  1       0       0        0
19       A 1988  1       0       0        0
20       B 1970  0       0       0        0
21       B 1971  0       0       0        0
22       B 1972  0       0       0        0
23       B 1973  0       0       1        0
24       B 1974  0       1       1        0
25       B 1975  0       1       1        0
26       B 1976  0       1       1        0
27       B 1977  0       1       1        0
28       B 1978  1       0       0        1
29       B 1979  1       0       0        1
30       B 1980  1       0       0        1
31       B 1981  1       0       0        1
32       B 1982  1       0       0        1
33       B 1983  1       0       0        0
34       B 1984  1       0       0        0
35       B 1985  1       0       0        0
36       B 1986  1       0       0        0
37       B 1987  1       0       0        0
38       B 1988  1       0       0        0
39       C 1970  1       0       0        1
40       C 1971  0       0       0        1
41       C 1972  0       0       0        1
42       C 1973  0       0       0        1
43       C 1974  0       0       0        1
44       C 1975  0       0       0        0
45       C 1976  0       0       0        0
46       C 1977  0       0       0        0
47       C 1978  0       0       0        0
48       C 1979  0       0       1        0
49       C 1980  0       1       1        0
50       C 1981  0       1       1        0
51       C 1982  0       1       1        0
52       C 1983  0       1       1        0
53       C 1984  1       0       0        1
54       C 1985  1       0       0        1
55       C 1986  1       0       0        1
56       C 1987  1       0       0        1
57       C 1988  1       0       0        1
58       C 1989  1       0       0        0
59       C 1990  1       0       0        0
60       C 1991  1       0       0        0
```

It corresponds to your desired output in majority of cases, however from row 39 onwards you don't have it marked as post-agreement - though it occurred in 1970. Either a typo or you'll need to further explain the logic.

Comment: thanks for this @arg0naut91. I'm working on it but it doesn't seem to work on my real data. I wonder whether is it because I have NAs, or because the data starts from 1919 to 2018...

Comment: May be multiple things. Do you get an error or what doesn't work exactly?